# "You can't delete contacts from read-only accounts."

Tags: contacts, google-account

I'm trying to delete contacts from my Google account that's synced with my Nexus 5. It's synced as a Google account, not using Gmail IMAP or anything like that, but *all* of the contacts display this message when I try to delete them:

```
You can't delete contacts from read-only accounts, but you can hide them
in your contacts lists.
```

I don't understand why the Contacts app (default, from Google) is saying my Google account contacts are read-only. How do I correct this problem so I can fully edit contacts from my phone?

Comment: Tried both the proposed solutions, yet it still get the same warning. In the end I deleted unwanted contacts via the `Contacts` interface within desktop `Gmail`.

Comment: In case, this happen when add contacts wia others application, like whatsapp. The only way I found to delete this is going to contacts.google.com from some PC/laptop

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried going into the **Apps list** (the All tab) and clearing data for **Contacts** and **Contacts Storage**?

Once that's done you can *resync* your phone with **Google** to get all of your original contacts back.

Comment: Mohammed your advice made me delete all my contacts

Answer (score 0):

^ What he said!

However, I had to CLEAR and STOP both Contacts and Contacts-Storage.

1. Goto settings: Apps
2. Goto ALL TAB
3. Open: contacts: Clear-data, Clear-Cache, Force-stop
4. Open: Contacts-Storage: Clear-data, Clear-Cache, Force-stop
5. Goto settings: Accounts
6. Open: Google: Select (your) account
7. Select: Contacts: Toggle on/off (force sync)
8. You may have to force sync twice
9. Open your contacts app
10. Only contacts from Google-Contacts should be there
11. If not, you may have other contact accounts, or contacts stored on phone

Thanks!

In addition to this, being a Verizon customer I had to go into Accounts and disable the "Cloud" account.  Then I was able to delete contacts properly from the App. I believe the Cloud account is via Verizon and NOT Google which is where I rely on my backups/syncing to take place.  Great help otherwise.  Thanks.